# Simple jquery validation based on input value

Tags: jquery, validation

I have 2 text boxes and 1 submit button. Here once you click the submit button it will validate for:  1) Empty field one by one.  2) If the value of text field and password field is equal to 'admin' then it should redirect to some page. Here everything is working fine but the issue is when I put 'admin' on textfield and some other text on password field,the message 'Username does not match' should remove from textfield but here still showing unless I put 'admin' on both textfield and password field. Here is code below:

### HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" name="username">
            <p class="blankerroruser">Please enter username</p>
            <p class="redirectusererror">Username does not match</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" required class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
            <p class="blankerrorpwd">Please enter Password</p>
            <p class="redirectpwderror">Password does not match</p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

### Style

```
.blankerrorpwd,.redirectusererror,.redirectpwderror,.blankerroruser{ 
    display:none; 
    color:red;
}
```

### Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        if(($('#username').val()=='') && ($('#password').val()=='')){      
            $("p.blankerroruser").show();
            $("p.blankerrorpwd").show();
        } else if($('#username').val()==''){
            $("p.blankerroruser").show();
            $("p.blankerrorpwd").hide();
            $("p.redirectusererror").hide();
        } else if($('#password').val()==''){
            $("p.blankerrorpwd").show();
            $("p.blankerroruser").hide();
            $("p.redirectpwderror").hide();
        } else if(($('#username').val()=='admin') && ($('#password').val()=='admin')){
            $("p.redirectusererror").hide();
            $("p.redirectpwderror").hide();
            $(location).attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
        } else if(($('#password').val()!='') && ($('#username').val()!='') || ($('#username').val()!='admin') || ($('#password').val()!='admin')) { 
            $("p.blankerrorpwd").hide();
            $("p.blankerroruser").hide();
            $("p.redirectusererror").show();
            $("p.redirectpwderror").show();
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: If you have *any* security concerns, you will not perform password validation on the front end, ever.

Comment: yes you are correct but that is just dummy hardcoded  value as per our temporary requirement

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Any user is capable of inspecting their pages to find what you are validating the password against if you perform that validation on the front end.

Comment: yes I know but as of now this is our requirement just for demo

Comment: The behavior you describe is what you've coded. The only time the 'redirectusererror' p tag hides is when both username and password are admin or if username is blank.

Answer (score 0):

here is the validation of your code

```
$(function(){
    $('[type="button"]').click(function(){
        var error = false;
        $('input[required]').siblings('p').hide();      
        $('input[required]').each(function(k,v){
            switch($(v).attr('name')){
                case 'username' :
                    if($.trim($(this).val()).length > 0){
                        if($.trim($(this).val()) != 'admin'){ error = true; $("p.redirectusererror").show(); }
                    }else{ error = true; $("p.blankerroruser").show(); }
                break;
                case 'password' :
                    if($.trim($(this).val()).length > 0){
                        if($.trim($(this).val()) != 'admin'){ error = true; $("p.redirectpwderror").show(); }
                    }else{ error = true; $("p.blankerrorpwd").show(); }                 
                break;
            }
        });
        if(error === false){
            // success
            //console.log('submitted');         
            $(location).attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
        }
    });
});
```

working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Ljekm4z6/1/